# I am trying to install web3 module through npm

Tags: node.js, npm, blockchain, ethereum, web3js

[Latest code snippet to show what version of Web2.min.js I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mot1O.png)
[This is the warning i m getting in browser and i am able to intract with remix contract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUMb9.png)Command Used :C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\BC_Project>npm install web3
[providing the image showing error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRxZf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the things required for `node-gyp` environment?

- Python
- MSBuild Tools
- Visual C++ Build Tools core features
- Windows 8.1 SDK
- Windows 10 SDK (10.0.x.x)

Comment: I have Installed Node js v13.1.0 ,ganache-cli-develop and was trying installing web3.I am trying to connect to Remix with UI .

Comment: @AVINASHCHAUHAN I know, but do you have to make sure you have these requirements on your computer in order to install web3.js

Comment: I tried different version of Web3 to solve this out .When i used web3.min.js>1.0 ,web3.eth.contract was not identified as function.I looked into the documentation.JsonInterface object need to passed.I don't know why this is not working ,I am passing ABI as parameter.